# Setting TabContainer Active Tab dynamically by visibility

Tags: asp.net, tabs, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using AjaxControlToolkit `TabContainer` and dynamically setting `TabPanel` visiblility. When active tab is is hidden (dynamically) the whole Tab Control is hidden, so to avoid this I've written small method like this (setting first visible tab as Active Tab)

```
private void SetActiveTab()
{
    if (tabControl1.Tabs[0].Visible)
    {
        tabControl1.ActiveTabIndex =0;
        return;
    }

    if (tabControl1.Tabs[1].Visible)
    {
        tabControl1.ActiveTabIndex = 1;
        return;
    }

    ...

}
```

But this feels like but inefficient/ugly code for me..., Is there a better way of doing this...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose any

```
for (int tabIndex = 0; tabIndex < TabContainer1.Tabs.Count; tabIndex++)
{
    if(TabContainer1.Tabs[tabIndex].Visible)
    {
        TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex = tabIndex;
        break;
    }
}

foreach (TabPanel tab in TabContainer1.Tabs)
{
    if (tab.Visible)
    {
        TabContainer1.ActiveTab = tab;
        break;
    }
}

var firstVisibleTab = TabContainer1.Tabs.OfType<TabPanel>().FirstOrDefault(tab => tab.Visible);
if (firstVisibleTab != null)
{
    TabContainer1.ActiveTab = firstVisibleTab;
}
```

BTW for such quetions better use Code Review site: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1)